# Android: How to run some code on animation end

Tags: android, android-animation

On android I am trying to create a countdown animation which does two things:

1. it fades a square from green to white
2. upon execution it changes the context of a text view

The code is:

```
    int colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
    int colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
    ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
    colorAnimation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    colorAnimation.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
    colorAnimation.setDuration(30000); // milliseconds
    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator)
        {
            tv.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
        }

    });

    colorAnimation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
        {
            String authcode = getAuthCode(login_session);
            code.setText(authcode);            
        }
    });

    colorAnimation.start();
```

I am aware of [Detecting when ValueAnimator is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233558/detecting-when-valueanimator-is-done), that is from where I have ported the solution into my code, but it seemingly does not work for my case. The green to white fade works, but when it's done it just restarts the animation without setting a new text into the text view.

What am I doing wrongly and how can I set a new text when an animation ends?

Comment: Have you tried setting colorAnimation.setRepeatCount(0); and remove colorAnimation.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART); this line ?

Comment: try this colorAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this

Use this

```
colorAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
```

Instead of this

```
colorAnimation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
int colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
        int colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.lightWhite);
        ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
        colorAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
        colorAnimation.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
        colorAnimation.setDuration(3000); // milliseconds
        colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                tv.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            }

        });

        colorAnimation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
            {
                tv.setText("TEST");
            }
        });
        colorAnimation.start();
```

> **OR**

You can also use [**`AnimatorListenerAdapter`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorListenerAdapter.html)

> This adapter class provides empty implementations of the methods from `Animator.AnimatorListene`r. Any custom listener that cares only about a subset of the methods of this listener can simply subclass this adapter class instead of implementing the interface directly.

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);

        int colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
        int colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.lightWhite);
        ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
        colorAnimation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        //colorAnimation.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
        colorAnimation.setDuration(3000); // milliseconds
        colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                tv.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            }

        });

        colorAnimation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationCancel(animation);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                tv.setText("END");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationRepeat(animation);
                tv.setText("REPEAT");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationStart(animation);
                tv.setText("START");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationPause(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationPause(animation);
                tv.setText("PAUSE");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationResume(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationResume(animation);
                tv.setText("RESUME");
            }
        });

        colorAnimation.start();


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below `callback` for `addListener`

```
colorAnimation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
              String authcode = getAuthCode(login_session);
              code.setText(authcode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the this line of code

```
colorAnimation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
```

It will keep animating hence call back for animation end will never done.
If you just comment that line you will after 30 seconds(as you have suggested in the code) the call back for animation end will be done.

Answer (score 0):

Set **RepeatCount = 0**

```
colorAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
```

Instead of

```
colorAnimation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
```