# Animating a specific line of a textview using android Animations

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-animation

I am wondering if it is possible to perform a fade out/fade in animation on a specific line of a textview. I have a [two line textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGONn.png) which I would like the "title" to stay visible while the "data" fades out and in when it changes. I am attempting to limit the number of views on my fragment so separating the two lines into separate textviews is not preferable. I am fairly new to animations and was unsure if this is possible.

### Update

After Cheticamps answer I developed my own java version of his solution and wanted to post it here if anyone else was looking for this.

```
    ValueAnimator alphaAnim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(255,0).setDuration(1000);
        alphaAnim.addUpdateListener(valueAnimator -> {
            int alpha = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            int newColor = binding.ForegroundSpanText.getCurrentTextColor() & 0x00ffff | (alpha <<24);
            System.out.println("Color: "+ Integer.toHexString(newColor));
            SpannableString tempStringHolder = binding.getAnimString();
            if(fadingSpan !=null){
                tempStringHolder.removeSpan(fadingSpan);
            }
            fadingSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(newColor);
            tempStringHolder.setSpan(fadingSpan, 38, animStringHolder.length(), SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            binding.setAnimString(tempStringHolder);
        });
        alphaAnim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation){
                System.out.println("Finished");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a series of [ForegroundColorSpans](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan) on the section of the text that you want to fade. Each successive *ForegroundColorSpan* will decrease the alpha of the text color until the alpha value is zero. (Alpha == 255 is fully visible; alpha == 0 is invisible.)

Animation of the alpha value of the text color associated with the *ForegroundColorSpan* can be accomplished with a [ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator). The following shows this technique.

The TextViw is simply

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:bufferType="spannable"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello\nWorld!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="48sp"/>
```

The code is wrapped in a button's click listener for demo purposes:

```
var fadingSpan: ForegroundColorSpan? = null
val spannable = binding.textView.text as Spannable
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
    // android:bufferType="spannable" must be set on the TextView for the following to work.
    // Alpha value varies from the 255 to zero. (We are assuming the starting alpha is 255.)
    ValueAnimator.ofInt(255, 0).apply {
        duration = 3000 // 3 seconds to fade
        // Update listener is called for every tick of the animation.
        addUpdateListener { updatedAnimation ->
            // Get the new alpha value and incorporate it into the color int (AARRGGBB)
            val newAlpha = updatedAnimation.animatedValue as Int
            val newColor =
                binding.textView.currentTextColor and 0x00ffff or (newAlpha shl 24)
            if (fadingSpan != null) {
                spannable.removeSpan(fadingSpan)
            }
            fadingSpan = ForegroundColorSpan(newColor)
            spannable.setSpan(
                fadingSpan,
                6,
                12,
                SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
        }
        start()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful thank you! Is there a way to notify my program when the text alpha reaches 0?

Comment: @TonyL. Add a listener. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20362871/6287910).